# java: getRuntime().exec() passing arguments to a Python program

Tags: java, python, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass run and pass arguments into a python program and am having trouble.
Here's what I'm doing now:

```
String[] testCases=readIn("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\development\\"+folder+"\\testCases.txt");
                String arguements="";
                for(int i=0; i<testCases.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        arguements=testCases[i]+" ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    arguements=arguements+testCases[i]+" ";
                }
                command= new String[]{"C:\\Python27\\python.exe","C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\development\\"+fileName, arguements};
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm passing in the arguments correctly. Is there some way that I need to indicate that they are arguments that my Python code will talk in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed passing the arguments wrong. You need to pass each argument as a string in the `command` array. e.g.,

```
command = new String[arguments.length + 2];
command[0] = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
command[1] = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\development\\" + fileName;
System.arraycopy(arguments, 0, command, 2, arguments.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the final command that you get to the console and execute that in command line.
You will be able to dig down the exact error.